# $\frac{dy_t}{dt} = a \frac{dx_t}{dt} + x_t +y_t$ with $x_t$ Ornstein Uhlenbeck process - what to do? [UNRESOLVED]

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I consider the following equation:
$$\frac{dy_t}{dt}  = a \frac{dx_t}{dt} + x_t +y_t, \tag{1}$$ 
where $a=$ constant and where $x_t$ follows an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) under Alternative representation for nonstationary processes):
$$x_t=x_0 e^{-\theta t} +\mu (1-e^{-\theta t})+
{\sigma\over\sqrt{2\theta}}e^{-\theta t}W_{e^{2\theta t}-1}. \tag{2} $$

For $\sigma = 0$ there is no problem => By substituting Eq.(2) into Eq.(1), we get an ODE.

For $\sigma >0$ there is a problem. The problem is that when I substitute Eq.(2) into Eq.(1), I will have to differentiate the Brownian motion term. Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

---

Can someone please help me out? I would like to present the solution eventually in for instance in some plot. If useful, numerical methods to solve are also fine for me.

Comment: You mean in the ordinary way from basic analysis? If so: No. With probability 1, the brownian motion (and any other local martingale) are not differentiable in any point. 

Thus it follows that this function cannot be differentiable either.

Comment: I'd suggest a read though the following wiki page. I'm not quite sure where you're going with your edit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itō_calculus

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship between $y_t$ and $x_t$ satisfies:
$$\frac{dy_t}{dt}  = a \frac{dx_t}{dt} , \tag{1}$$

If $x_t$ were differentiable (which it isn't) then 
$$y_t = a x_t + b$$
where $b$ is a constant with respect to $t$ would satisfy that equation.

As I mentioned in the comments, you can make your relationship make sense by instead turning it into an integral equation:
$$y_t = y_0 + a\int_0^t dx_s$$

Comment: I have edited the post to consider a more complicated equation.. is it then still possible? Sorry for the edit but I would like to understand it more generally..